# Parsing csv into JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing, csv

I am trying to parse a csv file into javascript. I downloaded https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv into a local directory under the name seen in line 8. The map doesn't display at all. If I take out line 14, the map displays perfectly. Any assistance is appreciated.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html> 
    <head> 
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
      <title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title> 
      <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
              type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="jquery-1.11.1.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="jquery.csv-0.71.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>

    </head> 
    <body>
      <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>

      <script type="text/javascript">
        var data = $.csv.toObjects("Database.csv");
        var locations = [
          ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
          ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
          ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
          ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
          ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
        ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you also loading jQuery?

Comment: Load jQuery first. as jQuery-csv has it as dependency.

Comment: Any kind of JavaScript error?

Comment: Was dumb, loading jQuery first and now it works. Thanks so much, my mistake.